# subtract custom field from field in jaspersoft studio

Tags: jasper-reports

I have fields generated from sql query, and a custom field that is a sum of some fields in the query.

I'm using JasperSoft Studio Community Edition 6.6.0.

I need to subtract the custom field from a sql field.

Here's the sql field from which the custom field is to be subtracted.

```
<textField>
    <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="55" height="30" uuid="46c5ae51-1356-4067-b109-ea071fb8ba1f"/>
    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{Leave_Days}]]></textFieldExpression>
</textField>
```

Here's the custom field that is a sum of few sql fields.

```
<textField>
    <reportElement positionType="Float" x="0" y="0" width="36" height="30" uuid="12d28ae3-3d03-4814-9c1f-a0257f6fbba6"/>
    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[SUM( $F{jan},$F{feb},$F{mar},$F{apr},$F{jun},$F{jul},$F{aug},$F{sep},$F{oct},$F{nov},$F{may},$F{dece})]]></textFieldExpression>
</textField>
```

This is where I need the subtracted field.

```
<textField>
    <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="38" height="30" uuid="4f721549-03d1-4c87-9bc7-708988a5dd09"/>
    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{Leave_Days} - SUM($F{jan},$F{feb},$F{mar},$F{apr},$F{jun},$F{jul},$F{aug},$F{sep},$F{oct},$F{nov},$F{may},$F{dece})]]> )]]></textFieldExpression>
</textField>
```

I hope I am making sense. How do I subtract these two fields and make a new custom field.

Comment: Hi, you can use [variable](https://community.jaspersoft.com/documentation/tibco-jaspersoft-studio-user-guide/v60/defining-new-variable-or-editing-existing-one) to store the result of an operation

Comment: What is the problem?, error? Show your current output and expected output